# Doctest: How can I identify differences between expected and actual output?

Tags: python, pandas, doctest

In the below doctest, the expected and actual output look identical. I'm pretty sure there is some white space error since when I enable `NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE`, the test is successful.  Is there another flag that can help a user triangulate on the location of such a whitespace error?

```
"""
>>> df  # doctest:-NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
              Open
Date
2021-05-17  126.82
"""

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2021-05-17'], 'Open': [126.82]}).set_index('Date')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

```
Failed example:
    df  # doctest:-NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
Expected:
                  Open
    Date
    2021-05-17  126.82
Got:
                  Open
    Date
    2021-05-17  126.82
```

Comment: Have you tried copying the text into a diff tool, like Meld or [DiffChecker.com](https://www.diffchecker.com/) for example? I tried it myself but there's no difference between the "Expected" and "Got". Maybe the line endings are different? I'm not sure if that's possible. Also this is a lot of code and a lot of data. Please make a [mre].

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks for taking a look.  I also tried a diff tool called 'Beyond Compare' but came up empty.  Also thought maybe `TAB`s were treated differently than spaces but no luck there either.  Wondering if there's a built-in debugger within the `doctest` class that can help users triangulate on the line in the output where the problem occurs?  As for the minimal reproduceable example, it's less than 10 lines of code but understand what you mean because the dataframe output is large.  But this is an idiosyncratic case so any attempt to generalize might  have limited the reproducibility.

Comment: For the MRE, what I mean is, can you reproduce the same problem with only one row in the dataframe? What about zero rows, just the headers? What about just the `df['mbzu']` Series? Is `yf` relevant to the problem, or could you reproduce the problem with a different dataframe? Are the calculations actually relevant, or could you reproduce the problem with just the bare output from `yf.download()`? The problem itself might not be idiosyncratic once you isolate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the flag [`REPORT_NDIFF`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#doctest.REPORT_NDIFF). The docs say, "This is the only method that marks differences within lines as well as across lines", which will help identify any whitespace problems, for example:

```
"""
>>> print('Hello goodbye')
Hello goodbye\r
"""
```

```
Failed example:
    print('Hello goodbye')
Differences (ndiff with -expected +actual):
    - Hello goodbye
    ?              -
    + Hello goodbye
```

Note that the carriage return doesn't actually appear here.

---

In this particular case, the problem is that dataframes with an index name have trailing whitespace, so it's failing on `Date` vs `Date`   [...]. The whitespace in the docstring was probably stripped by your editor ([which is good](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#other-recommendations), and `NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE` is the right tool to account for that), but I'm not sure why it was stripped from the "Got" output too — maybe your terminal did that (which is not good) or maybe you pasted it into your editor then copied that to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.  I was able to identify the location of the problem.  Unfortunately, however, I'm unable to diagnose the location of the whitespace and subsequently rectify the problem. `Differences (ndiff with -expected +actual):
                    Open    High     Low   Close  Adj Close    Volume  mbzu  mbzu_stop
    - Date
    + Date ` - The expected output (i.e. `Date`) and the actual look exactly the same.

Comment: @jgg Coming back to this, I realized that dfs with an index label have trailing whitespace, so it was failing on `Date` vs `Date   `[...]. The whitespace in the docstring was probably stripped by your editor (which is good, and `NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE` is the right tool for that), but I'm not sure why it was stripped from the output too - maybe your terminal did that (which is not good) or maybe you pasted it into your editor then copied that to Stack Overflow. Not to harp on, but it would have been easier to identify with a [mre]. See also [reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).